# Why is the "is"-operator in an if a longer scope then the if?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

So my question is:

Why (and maybe how to avoid it) has the Is-operator in C# a longer lifetime as used in an if?

Example:

```
Animal a = new Cat();
if (a is Cat c)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c); // Works
}

Console.WriteLine(c); // Works too

// Leads to an error because c is allready declared
if (a is Cat c)
{
    ....
}
```

What I would expect is, that because I declared the variable c within the if-condition, that it will be scoped to that if-condition, what is not true.

Edit:
I understand the bracket argument (a scope starts with the bracked and ends with it).
BUT

Why is a for loop that different then?

```
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
....
}

Console.WriteLine(i) // error
```

Comment: A scope starts with an opening curly brace and not a single character before ... thats it

Comment: @SirRufo See my edit

Comment: _Console.WriteLine(c); // Works too_   does it really???

Comment: @TaW Yes, in the context of this question (scope of variable)

Comment: Not here. I can't reproduce.

Comment: [Me neither...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5hwm4j)  Compilation error (line 12, col 21): Use of unassigned local variable 'c'

Comment: @TaW The error is "use of an unassigned variable" so the variable is known and in the scope which does not compared to the for loop

Comment: @Sir Rufo this is a compilation error... how can you say it works?!

Comment: @ZoharPeled Because we are talking about the **scope** of variables

Comment: @Sir: Ah, right, I missed that. Interesting and good to know! So Hasan's answer nails it.

Comment: Also [well documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern): "If expr is true and is is used with an if statement, varname is assigned within the if statement only. The scope of varname is from the is expression to the end of the block enclosing the if statement. Using varname in any other location generates a compile-time error for use of a variable that has not been assigned."

Comment: Mayby this question had be worded as: In which situation may it be useful to have such a "long" scope? If there is no, then we should add a feature request to c# language

Comment: Here's an example of where it's useful: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/c1767f937595e39d2aab6b9c4fe64d89 I believe the language team debated this for months (possibly years!) with lots of different options.

Comment: Jon Skeet honors us with his presence :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You expectations may not always match the language specifications all the time. I think you may already know then name but what you are using is called `Pattern Matching`.
Here are the rules for the scope of [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression) taken from MSDN (I am copy an pasting the related section:

```
public static double ComputeAreaModernIs(object shape)
{
   if (shape is Square s)
       return s.Side * s.Side;
   else if (shape is Circle c)
       return c.Radius * c.Radius * Math.PI;
   else if (shape is Rectangle r)
       return r.Height * r.Length;
    // elided
    throw new ArgumentException(
        message: "shape is not a recognized shape",
        paramName: nameof(shape));
}
```

> The variable c is in scope only in the else branch of the first if statement. The variable s is in scope in the method ComputeAreaModernIs. That's because each branch of an if statement establishes a separate scope for variables. However, the if statement itself doesn't. That means variables declared in the if statement are in the same scope as the if statement (the method in this case.) This behavior isn't specific to pattern matching, but is the defined behavior for variable scopes and if and else statements.

Simply put your scope will start with `{` and end with`}`

Comment: But with that argument in a for loop the variable that is declared as the countin variable (e.g. int i = 0) should be available after the loop itself too... right?

Comment: The for loop documentation clearly states: "The declaration and initialization of a local loop variable, which can't be accessed from outside the loop."

Comment: The behaviour  of the `for`-loop changed in 4th version of C#