# How to get around use of unassigned variable that can never happen?

Tags: c#, unassigned-variable

In the following piece of code, the compiler gives a "Use of unassigned local variable" on 'intValue' on the return line. However, there is no case where "intValue > 500" will be reached where it will be unassigned (because if `intValue` is unassigned, then `valueIsInt` is false, and the statement returns false before reaching `intValue`)

Is there a way to get around this issue without modifying the **logic** or **business logic** of the code? This is a very simplified example; in a case where `intValue` is another type and the condition `intValue > 500` is more complex, we can't simply give intValue a value in the `else` block like `intValue = 0`

```
bool valueIsInt;

if (value is int intValue)
{
    valueIsInt = true;
}
else
{
    valueIsInt = false;
}

return valueIsInt && intValue > 500;
```

I want to avoid this in case the code in the else statement is more complex:

```
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Such as this:

```
bool valueIsInt;

if (value is int intValue)
{
    valueIsInt = true;
}
else
{
    if (value is string stringValue)
        valueIsInt = int.TryParse(stringValue, out intValue);
    else
        return false;
}

return valueIsInt && intValue > 500;
```

Comment: just set an initial value? bool valueIsInt = false;

Comment: You do realize you can write it as `return value is int intValue && intValue > 500;`, right? I mean, I know you wrote the sample is simplified buy if it resembles your code in any way you can probably re-write at least parts of it

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933935/43846) - _"Some variables are not classified as initially assigned; local variables in particular are not initially assigned. They must be classified by the compiler as **"definitely assigned"** at all points where their values are used."_ and further on _"**The reason this is illegal in C# is because using an unassigned local has high likelihood of being a bug**. We simply make it illegal, and then the compiler prevents you from ever having such a bug"_

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but here's a [question asking why this happens.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62978951/3094533)

Comment: For clarification, in response to these comments: I know the snippet of code can be simplified, that is not the question, and although I thank you for your kind intentions, the suggestions don't answer my real question. I have added clarifications in the question iteslef.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

```cs
static bool IsValueGreaterThan500(object value)
{
    try
    {
        // Converts the value to int if it is not already an int
        // from bool, short, float, double, string, etc.
        return Convert.ToInt32(value) > 500;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does TypeScript have to do with this question at all...? Also it is most certainly not smarter, it would have the same problem in this snippet. TypeScript would be *more* verbose as pattern matching isn't a thing.

Comment: I don't know what TypeScript has to do with it, but the c# part of this answer is solid :-)

Comment: TypeScript further distinguish true and false as different types during static type analysis of every branch such that the compiler would know whether the expression after && may be evaluated, and thus knows intValue must be assigned if valueIsInt is true. Though you're right, there is no pattern matching.

Comment: @TimTimWong I converted the asker's code in the TypeScript playground and did not observe the behavior you describe. I get "Variable 'intValue' is used before being assigned." What you're describing sounds rather fantastical.

Comment: Oops, I was confused how type narrowing and type guards work in TypeScript. It only applies inside the scope of the conditional branch.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question, it offers a working version of the code I wrote (only as an example). I have added more detail in the question to clarify what kind of answer is expected.

Comment: Do you mean to compare the numeric value whenever possible? See my updated answer.